# Target link href="" with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target following with jQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
```

What I cannot figure out is how to set default path (css folder) ?

```
<button data-button="test">Just a Test</button>


<script>
var button = $('button'),
    link = $('link'),
    stylesheet = $(this).data('button');

    button.on('click', function() {
        console.log(this);
        link.attr('href', stylesheet + '.css');
});
</script>
```

Right now this would change css on button click only if css is in root... So how do I tell him that CSS default path is at "css/".

Trying to find without success.

P.S. One question releated to JS but not to question title.

What is more perferred and correct:

```
var $something = $('#something');
or
var something = $('#something');
```

Comment: Using `$` in variable names is just a stylistic preference. There's nothing about it that's more "correct".

Comment: Changing the `link` after the page has loaded won't do anything; you'd have to load another stylesheet instead.

Comment: I would go for the second declaration style, as adding a $ in front of a variabale name can be confusing as its role (a lot of custom jquery methodes beginning by $) without giving real information (jquery object can really be just anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As easy as this

```
link.attr('href', 'css/' + stylesheet + '.css');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to switch stylesheet, you should use [alternate stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.en.html) instead.

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css/test1.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css/test2.css" disabled>
```

In jQuery you can then remove/add the `disabled` property to switch stylesheets:

```
var links = $("link[rel='alternate stylesheet']");
var button = $("button");

button.on('click', function() {
    links.filter(":disabled").prop("disabled", false).siblings().prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: Well it is interesting to learn new things. However for some reason, my sample does replace stylesheet for me on localhost even if it is not included anywhere. Thats odd...

Tried your script and nothing is happening, guess I need to play with it.

Comment: Not really sure in what context you are doing this, but you might need a default stylesheet as well (one that is not alternate).

Comment: I see! Then I suggest you get it working with *alternate stylesheet* instead since that is what they are for ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply mention the path `css/` in the code itself

```
link.attr('href', 'css/'+stylesheet + '.css');
```

To answer to your other question,

`var $something` and `var something` are both valid variable names. Your pick.